# minio client shows 0B after listing buckets

Tags: minio

when i get LS using mc it shows the bucket with 0B data which is wrong and they have data, what is the problem? how can i fix this ?

```
C:\Users\user\Downloads>mc ls ca
[2022-11-06 17:27:33 PST]     0B ca-db/
[2022-10-26 02:06:21 PDT]     0B ca-categories/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

S3 API does not have a way to provide size via ListBuckets() request, so 0B is just a placeholder value.

We could add a size parameter however we are a bit hesitant to add additional fields that might break ListBuckets() for some SDKs that are stricter in terms of parsing.

So what you are seeing is expected and under the current limitations.

Comment: Could you please take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74597862/which-s3-policy-types-are-supported-in-minio