# Which s3 policy types are supported in MINIO?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam, access-control, minio

I am investigating minio. For now I have docker-compose with minio service and minio console is available for me. As I understand minio is kinda replacement for amazon s3.

I've found the following page:
http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html

[image]
So there are 5 policy types in amazon S3

- IAM Policy
- S3 Bucket Policy
- SNS Topic Policy
- VPC Endpoint Policy
- SQS Queue Policy

Which of them are supported in minio ? Is there any abilities to configure it through minio console?
I can't find it in minio documentation for some reasons

Answer (score 1):

IAM Policy - you can read about them in detail https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/administration/identity-access-management.html

MinIO supports LDAP, Multiple IDP vendors, mTLS-based client authentication, and various other styles of access management - more than what AWS S3 does mostly to cater to all the on-prem needs.

Comment: I've read it but I haven't found clear mapping between AWS policies.

Our idea is create application and integrate it with minio and  if we want to replace MINIO with AWS S3 later -  we should be able to do it without any code changes.

Comment: https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/administration/identity-access-management/policy-based-access-control.html#supported-s3-policy-actions here are the policy actions

Comment: Which API endpoints support those  policy actions ?